# Why does this function call behave sensibly after calling it through a typecasted function pointer?

Tags: c++, gcc, function-pointers

I have the following code. There is a function that takes two int32. Then I take a pointer to it and cast it to a function that takes three int8 and call it. I expected a runtime error but program works fine. Why this even possible?

main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void f(int32_t a, int32_t b) {
    cout << a << " " << b << endl;
}

int main() {
    cout << typeid(&f).name() << endl;
    auto g = reinterpret_cast<void(*)(int8_t, int8_t, int8_t)>(&f);
    cout << typeid(g).name() << endl;
    g(10, 20, 30);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
PFviiE
PFvaaaE
10 20
```

As I can see the signature of the first function requires two ints and the second function requires three chars. Char is smaller than int and I wondered why a and b are still equals to 10 and 20.

Comment: Using `reinterpret_cast` may obfuscate anything.

Comment: It's undefined behavior, which means the result might or might not be what you expect.

Comment: "It's UB" only means that it is allowed, not that it is possible.

Comment: @harold for some definitions of "allowed"

Comment: @harold: Actually, "UB" means that in a practical sense it is _not_ allowed - unless you consider it acceptable for your software to randomly crash or produce wrong results, which is what UB means.

Comment: OK I get it, you guys are reading my comment as "the code is allowed", but I meant the behaviour. Though the code is apparently allowed as well, if it resulted in a compile error we wouldn't be having this question in the first place.

Comment: IMHO, the question is "what is the underlying mechanism for the observed behaviour?", rather than "how come the compiler allowed this?!? [horrified voice]".

Answer (score 37):

As others have pointed out, this is undefined behavior, so all bets are off about what may in principle happen. But assuming that you're on an x86 machine, there's a plausible explanation as to why you're seeing this.

On x86, the g++ compiler doesn't always pass arguments by pushing them onto the stack. Instead, it stashes the first few arguments into registers. If we disassemble the `f` function, notice that the first few instructions move the arguments out of registers and explicitly onto the stack:

```
    push    rbp
    mov     rbp, rsp
    sub     rsp, 16
    mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-4], edi  # <--- Here
    mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-8], esi  # <--- Here
    # (many lines skipped)
```

Similarly, notice how the call is generated in `main`. The arguments are placed into those registers:

```
    mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rbp-8]
    mov     edx, 30      # <--- Here
    mov     esi, 20      # <--- Here
    mov     edi, 10      # <--- Here
    call    rax
```

Since the entire register is being used to hold the arguments, the size of the arguments isn't relevant here.

Moreover, because these arguments are being passed via registers, there's no concern about resizing the stack in an incorrect way. Some calling conventions (`cdecl`) leave the caller to do cleanup, while others (`stdcall`) ask the callee to do cleanup. However, neither really matters here, because the stack isn't touched.

Comment: That looks like a lot of unnecessary effort to explain the potential results of UB. +1 nonetheless, since the first sentence answers the quesion.

Comment: @Fureeish I've often found that when you get undefined behavior, it's still sometimes helpful to see what's actually happening. It often teaches you a lot about what the compiler is doing behind the scenes!

Comment: @Fureeish Law of leaky abstractions and whatnot, this is as good a a place as any for discussing what compilers are doing under the hood.

Comment: Worth noting is that this behavior is decided by the ABI being targeted, not the compiler (this is what enables you to link a library compiled with gcc to an executable compiled with clang). The rules for parameter passing get a little messy when returning/passing by value, but in general, the first 6 parameters will be passed via register. See here for more info: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#List_of_x86_calling_conventions

Answer (score 9):

As others have pointed out, it's probably **undefined behavior**, but old school C programmers know this type of thing to work.

Also, because I can sense the language lawyers drafting their litigation documents and court petitions for what I'm about to say, I'm going to cast a spell of `undefined behavior discussion`. It's cast by saying `undefined behavior` three times while tapping my shoes together. And that makes the language lawyers disappear so I can explain why weird things just happen to work without getting sued.

Back to my answer:

Everything I discuss below is compiler specific behavior. All of my simulations are with Visual Studio compiled as 32-bit x86 code. I suspect it will work the same with gcc and g++ on a similar 32-bit architecture.

**Here's why your code just happens to work and some caveats.**

1. When function call arguments get pushed onto the stack, they get pushed in reverse order. When `f` is invoked normally, the compiler generates code to push the `b` argument onto the stack before the `a` argument.  This helps facilitate variadic argument functions such as printf.  So when your function, `f` is accessing `a` and `b`, it's just accessing arguments at the top of the stack. When invoked through `g`, there was an extra argument pushed to the stack (30), but it got pushed first. 20 was pushed next, followed by 10 which is at the top of the stack. `f` is only looking at the top two arguments on the stack.
2. IIRC, at least in classic ANSI C, chars and shorts, always get promoted to int before being placed on the stack.  That's why, when you invoked it with `g`, the literals 10 and 20 get placed on the stack as full sized ints instead of 8-bit ints.  However, the moment you redefine `f` to take 64-bit longs instead of 32-bit ints, the output of your program changes.

```
    void  f(int64_t a, int64_t b) {
        cout << a << " " << b << endl;
    }
```

Results in this getting output by your main (with my compiler)

```
85899345930 48435561672736798
```

And if you convert to hex:

```
140000000a effaf00000001e
```

`14` is `20` and `0A` is `10`.  And I suspect that `1e` is your `30` getting pushed to the stack.  So the arguments got pushed to the stack when invoked through `g`, but were munged up in some compiler specific way. (**undefined behavior** again, but you can see the arguments got pushed).

3. When you invoke a function, the usual behavior is that the calling code will fix up the stack pointer upon return from a called function. Again, this is for the sake of variadic functions and other legacy reasons for compat with K&R C. `printf` has no idea how many arguments you actually passed to it, and it relies on the caller to fix the stack when it returns.  So when you invoked through `g`, the compiler generated code to push 3 integers to the stack, invoke the function, and then code to pop those same values off.   The moment, you change your compiler option to have the callee clean up the stack (ala `__stdcall` on Visual Studio):

```
    void  __stdcall f(int32_t a, int32_t b) {
        cout << a << " " << b << endl;
    }
```

Now you are clearly in undefined behavior territory.  Invoking through `g` pushed three int arguments onto the stack, but the compiler only generated code for `f` to pop two int arguments off the stack when it returns.  The stack pointer is corrupted upon return.

Comment: The whole thing is undefined behaviour territory, it is UB to call a function via a function pointer of incompatible type to the actual function type

Answer (score 1):

As other have pointed out, it is entirely undefined behaviour, and what you get will depend on the compiler. It will work only if you have a specific call convention, that doesn't use the stack but registers to pass the parameters.

I used Godbolt to see the assembly generated, that you can check in full [here](https://godbolt.org/z/Q97jZs)

The relevant function call is here:

```
mov     edi, 10
mov     esi, 20
mov     edx, 30
call    f(int, int) #clang totally knows you're calling f by the way
```

It doesn't push parameters on the stack, it simply puts them in registers. What is most interesting is that the `mov` instruction doesn't change just the lower 8 bits of the register, but all of them as it is a 32-bit move. This also means that no matter what was in the register before, you will always get the right value when you read 32 bits back as f does.

If you wonder why the 32-bit move, it turns out that in almost every case, on a x86 or AMD64 architecture, compilers will always use either 32 bit literal moves or 64 bit literal moves (if and only if the value is too big for 32 bits). Moving a 8 bit value doesn't zero out the upper bits (8-31) of the register, and it can create problems if the value would end up being promoted. Using a 32-bit literal instruction is more simple than having one additional instruction to zero out the register first.

One thing you have to remember though is it is really trying to call `f` as if it had 8 bits parameters, so if you put a large value it will truncate the literal. For example, `1000` will become `-24`, as the lower bits of `1000` are `E8`, which is `-24` when using signed integers. You will also get a warning

```
<source>:13:7: warning: implicit conversion from 'int' to 'signed char' changes value from 1000 to -24 [-Wconstant-conversion]
```

Answer (score 0):

The first C compiler, as well as most compilers that preceded the publication of the C Standard, would process a function call by pushing arguments in right-to-left order, use the platform's "call subroutine" instruction to invoke the function, and then then after the function returned, pop whatever arguments were pushed.  Functions would assign addresses to their arguments in sequential order starting just past whatever information had been pushed by the "call" instruction.

Even on platforms such as the Classic Macintosh where responsibility for popping arguments would normally lie with the called function (and where failing to push the right number of arguments would often corrupt the stack), C compilers typically used a calling convention that behaved like the first C compiler.  A "pascal" qualifier was needed when calling, or on functions that were called by, code written in other languages (such as Pascal).

In most implementations of the language that existed before the Standard, one could write a function:

```
int foo(x,y) int x,y
{
  printf("Hey\n");
  if (x)
  { y+=x; printf("y=%d\n", y); }
}
```

and invoke it as e.g. `foo(0)` or `foo(0,0)`, with the former being slightly faster.  Attempting to call it as e.g. `foo(1);` would likely corrupt the stack, but if the function never used object `y` there was no need to pass it.  Supporting such semantics would not have been practical on all platforms, however, and in most cases the benefits of argument validation outweigh the cost, so the Standard does not require that implementations be capable of supporting that pattern, but allows those that can support the pattern conveniently to extend the language by doing so.